# Updating a widget on screen unlock

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget and I want to auto-update it on one occasion only and that is when the user unlocks his phone. This is a requirement I have and it is not negotiable.

So how do I do that? How can I make sure that I get any callback of any kind when the user unlocks the screen. The update of the widget does not need to be instant. It is enough if it updates a couple of seconds after the screen is unlocked.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_USER_PRESENT
You can try to use BroadcastReceiver that listens for this event and then update your widget

Comment: Thank you for you answer but that will not work since there is a risk that the Android OS kill your application (and by that also your receiver class) while the device is asleep (or before the device goes to sleep). So since you cannot add Intent#ACTION_USER_PRESENT to your manifest, this solution will not work.